# Angular2 - Error in routing only on server, not in localhost

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Solution (its not really a solution, so i only put this in the question):

After all, its still the uppercase/lower case issue. My `overall-admin.routing.ts` file was in uppercase in the previous version, but i then changed them to lowercase. Yet my `module.ts` is still referring to `Overall-admin.routing.ts`(uppercase). Also, interestingly, there was a copy of the `Overall-admin.routing.js` in the server which is in uppercase. So the system keeps refer to the old `routing file`. When i deleted this old `routing file`, it then promote me an error on `module.ts` for

> 404, not found `Overall-admin.routing.js`

That's when i realize i am still referring to `Overall-admin.routing.ts`(uppercase) in my `module.ts`. After changing the reference to `overall-admin.routing.ts`(lowercase). It worked...

This is not really a technical aspect of things, but i hope if anyone who found this post can be more careful about their naming, and dont waste time and energy on 'debugging' these like me.

Original Post:

This question might be a bit unusual, but it indeed happened (sadly).

I am writing an angular2 web app, i was using lazy load to load into various components, and then navigate within these components.

All works fine but there is this specific one which works in my localhost (with npm start), yet, it doesnt work when i upload to server. It gave me this error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:
>   'overall-admin/confirm'

In which i will need to navigate to this new page when i press the button.

Below is part of my `routing.module.ts`:

```
const overallAdminRouting: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OverallAdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'confirm',
        component: OverallConfirmComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Followed by my `html`:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            (click)="submitFormEnable(adminForm.value)" 

            >Enable User</button>
```

Then my `component.ts`

```
submitFormDisable(value: any){
 this.router.navigate(['overall-admin/confirm']);
}
```

So when i press the button `Enable User`, the `component.ts` is supposed to navigate to `['overall-admin/confirm']` to display the `OverallConfirmComponent`.

But like i mentioned above, it worked in my localhost, yet, not on my server. 
I tried to eliminate all cases difference, multiple files with different cases, all doesnt work.

Any idea what i can do?

Comment: Try to enable `HashLocationStrategy`. If that fixes your issue, your server needs configuration changes to support HTML5 pushState

Comment: What's your server? Node? Is that error message from Node?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Thanks for the reply, i solved it. Please see the update in my question

Comment: @Gudin, Thanks for the reply, i solved it. Please see the update in my question